# MySQL 8 (current) W2K16 server fails to start

Tags: mysql

Brand new Xeon, 64gb, 2tb RAID 5 W2K16 server.  Installed current MySQL 8, setup as dedicated server and ran through setup just fine.

Was having problems with slow restores from mysqldump.sql file so after reading I sent to adjust the default 8M up to 32M just to try (Percona suggests up to 51G)

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
```

Restart the service and get the following error immediately after it starts:

The MySQL80 Service on Local Computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

I did see that it had changed the log on as to Network Service, so per some other stack questions I put it back to Local System Account and enabled can interact with desktop.

No dice.  Nothing I seem to do will get the server to start even though I immediately changed that innodb_buffer_pool_size back to 8M.

**UPDATE**

It seems it might have been a permissions issue.  I removed all traces of MySQL and reinstalled it.  I examined permissions on all directories and it looks like the configuration did not set the NETWORK SERVICE to have full control of the logs directory if it wasn't in it's default location under Data.

Comment: Let's see my.cnf -- there may be a subtle typo in it.

Comment: And, yes, 51G makes more sense if this will have a lot of data.

Comment: I restored my original copy.  Same thing - starts and then stops.  Logs just say it started.  Nothing in event viewer.  Changed the user back to Network Service and made sure that user at full permissions on the Data folder. Same thing.  Trying to do a complete remove and reinstall again.